# error in compiling but libraries required are mentioned

Tags: c, makefile

I made the following makefile to run a code

```
MODE := 3
FRICTION := 7
EREST:= 1

CC := gcc -g
CFLAGS := -lpthread -lGLU -lglut -lGL -lm
vpath %.h header
vpath %.c src
vpath %.o src
CFILES := aibot1.c start.c physics.c bothandler.c man.c manageer.c network.c rules.c msghandler.c
%.o: %.c headers.h
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o src/$@;
type:   
    @cd header;\
    echo "#define FRICTION $(FRICTION) \n#define MODE $(MODE) \n#define EREST $(EREST) \n" > mainhead1.h;\
    cd .. ;
carrom: type
    @cd src;\
    echo $(CFLAGS);\
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFILES) -o carrom;\
    mv carrom ..;\
```

but it showing me errors undefined reference to 'sqrt' and 'pthread_create', but I have included -lm and -lpthread respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Libraries needs to be specified *after* the files on your command line. It's also traditional to put them in `LDFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`.

With what you have, if you change:

```
$(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CFILES) -o carrom;
```

to:

```
$(CC) $(CFILES) -o carrom $(CFLAGS)
```

then it ought to work.

Also, you only need to specify libraries when linking, not when compiling (hence why they go in `LDFLAGS`, not `CFLAGS`), so in this line:

```
@$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o src/$@
```

specifying the libraries (which is all `CFLAGS` contains) does nothing.